# Python 2 - create executable program in Linux

Tags: python, linux, software-distribution

I am on Linux and i want to make executable file from my Tkinter application. If i run my program in python, it works. But if I create distribution with PyInstaller, some functions don´t work (I create it only with command "pyinstaller my_script.py"). 
Is there any other tool like pyinstaller? Or can I run pyinstaller with GUI? I preffer the simplest way. Thank you.

Comment: Which functions don't work? That should point to the underlying problem.

Comment: I have 3 files: main.py, script1.py and script2.py. I create dist with command "pyinstaller main.py". And functions, which are in main.py and script1.py, work. But functions in script2.py don´t work.

Comment: What exactly happens when you try to create a distribution using Pyinstaller? What errors do you get? Or is it that the installer is failing while you try to use it?

Comment: Still: which functions, what kind of functions, in `script2.py`? `Tkinter` related functions, all functions? I take it `script2.py` is imported in `main.py`? We'll need more details; currently, there is way too little information. Perhaps you can create a minimal set of small scripts that has your problem, then list the scripts.

Comment: I don´t get any error. I don´t know where is an error, because only functions in script2.py don´t work. I have these imported modules in script2.py: 
import os
import sys
import fnmatch
from xml.dom import minidom
import wave
from Tkinter import *

Comment: Try creating the executable with the `--debug` as well.